# Photoshop brush always fully opaque

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, brush

I am trying to follow a lesson on Digital Art where the instructor uses default Photoshop Hard Edge brush. However, he's brush is like this:

[image]

And my settings look exactly the same, but the preview of brush is different and also when I test draw, it draws fully opaque, no matter how soft or hard I press on my Drawing Pen:

[image]

I am not sure what settings I need to apply to get the same effect as the Instructor has, but in general, I think I have something wrong on my side, because drawing with fully opaque brush is not giving the results I would love with my paintings -- I could of course adjust the opacity of brush in the menu, but this is not comfortable to change all the time.

Comment: it's possible that he has pressure sensitivity enabled. That can produce effects like that.

Comment: Do you have a graphics tablet?  And if so, have you tried enabling pressure sensitivity in the Shape Dynamics in the brush settings?

Answer (score 1):

He is most likely using a graphics tablet or "pen tablet", that way the opacity and flow are determined by the pressure of the pen he is using.

To do this without a tablet you need to change the opacity and flow. Click on transfer and change "Control" to "Fade".

Tablet settings:

[image: Pressure Settings]